# Modify a line in a file located in the AppData folder of all users on a computer

Tags: powershell

I would like to modify a line in a file located in the AppData folder of all users on a computer.

The line to be changed in the `prefs.js` file begins with:

```
user_pref("mail.server.server1.directory", "C:\\Users\
```

I would replace the entire line:

```
user_pref("mail.server.server1.directory", "C:\\ Thunderbird Mail\\Local Folders")
```

I am doing this in each user profile.

I started a script, but it does not work:

```cs
$configFiles = Get-ChildItem C:\users\*\appdata prefs.js -rec
$ligne1 = 'user_pref("mail.server.server1.directory", "C:\\Users\'
$ligne2 = 'user_pref("mail.server.server1.directory", "C:\\Thunderbird\\Mail\\Local Folders");'
foreach ($file in $configFiles) {
    (Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
        ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $ligne1.+, $ligne2 } |
        Set-Content $file.PSPath
}
```

Comment: since there is only one active Thundebird profile per user, I 'd take an one user after the other approach. The gci with -rec is starting some dir levels to high. I'd begin with `$configfiles=Get-ChildItem C:\users\$env:username\appdata\roaming\Thunderbird\Profiles\*.default\prefs.js`

Comment: yes it's good LotPings !

In fact I would further modify the prefs.js file in each line but in a user list that is in a txt file

My biggest problem with this script is that I can not replace my a first value by the second because there are salsh and quotes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-replace` operator does regular expression replacements, so you need to escape special characters in your match string (`$ligne1`), particularly the backslashes and parentheses.

Replace this:

```
(Get-Content $file.PSPath) |
    ForEach-Object { $_ -replace $ligne1.+, $ligne2 } |
    Set-Content $file.PSPath
```

with this:

```
(Get-Content $file.FullName) -replace ([regex]::Escape($ligne1) + '.+'), $ligne2 |
    Set-Content $file.FullName
```

and the problem will disappear.

Comment: Thank's Ansgar ! It's work.
I want just a last question.
The $line1 must start with  user_pref("mail.server.server1.directory", "C:\\Users\ because after C:\users there is a lot of users.

Comment: What's the question? `Get-Content` produces an array of lines. `-replace` operates on each line separately. If you want to make sure `$ligne1` is at the beginning of the line prepend the expression with a caret (`-replace ('^' + [regex]::Esc...)`).

Comment: For example : 
The line is : user_pref("mail.server.server1.directory", "C:\\Users\toto\appdata\54654654\151555566\644454545454
i want to replace all the line by user_pref("mail.server.server1.directory", "C:\\ Thunderbird Mail\\Local Folders")
with my script the result is : user_pref("mail.server.server1.directory", "C:\\ Thunderbird Mail\\Local Folders")566\644454545454
the end of the line is not good because there is the end of the first line
it does not work with '^'

Comment: That's not possible if you had done what I suggested in my answer. Apparently you omitted the `+ '.+'` after the `[regex]::Escape()`.

Comment: Sorry, effectively i omitted the + '.+'